# Class Inheritance for members

Tags: javascript, inheritance, javascript-objects

I have an Octree class. A key feature of an Octree is that it can create its own children.

```
class Octree {
  ...
  createChildren(){
    ...
    /* for each of the 8 new children*/
    this.children.push(new Octree(/*someargs*/))
    ...
  }
}
```

Now I want to inherit off of the Octree class, however, I also want the children to become the inherited class. For example `class LODWorldTree extends Octree`, to additionally contain some renderer data for a game. However, if I call `LODWorldTree.createChildren()`, then `LODWorldTree.children` will be an array of `Octree`s instead of `LODWorldTree`s.

What is the best way to fix this problem? While writing this it occured to I could store `Octree.myClass = /*some inherited class*/`, and manually set this variable for all classes that inherit from `Octree`. Is there a better way to do something like this? Maybe with `this.prototype`?

Comment: Do you want that when you print `this.children` those are instances of the class which is inheriting?

Comment: The child class can override `createChildren()` with its own implementation, if you'd rather avoid using `this.constructor`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The objective it to find an implementation that doesn't require rewriting the fundamental core feature of the Octree. The whole point of inheritance is to avoid rewriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the fact that each object has a reference to it's own constructor via the prototype:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.val = 1;
    this.children = [];
    this.typeName = `I'm A`;
  }
  
  addSelfChild() {
    this.children.push(new this.constructor(this.val + 1));
  }
}

let a = new A(1);
a.addSelfChild();
a.addSelfChild();

console.dir(a);

class B extends A {
  constructor(val) {
    super(val);
    this.typeName = `I'm B`;
  }
}

let b = new B(1);
b.addSelfChild();
b.addSelfChild();

console.dir(b);
```

Comment: You might want to - instead of `this.constructor` - use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor`. While the latter is more verbose, it will continue to function properly when 'this' happens to have an own property 'constructor' of any type.

Comment: Your `val` doesn't appear to do anything, but other than that, this will work. Thanks.

Comment: @GreenFox - `val` is only there to show how to apply this solution with your `/*someargs*/` requirement.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp while `getPrototypeOf(...)` is useful for some cases, I'd argue that `constructor` is a language feature that shouldn't be tampered with. I'd personally reject code that did that. For this reason, I don't see the benefit in the added verbosity.

Comment: I totally agree with that being a bad practice. Still, it's a possibility, and this is an easy fix. At least it's worth consideration, and might be valuable for other visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `constructor` attribute:

```
this.children.push(new this.constructor(/*someargs*/));
```

`this.constructor` is the reference for constructor for current object, so invoking it will produce new instance of the same class